# PyQt5 Methods Not Showing

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt4, pyqt6

I am trying to build a user interface for controlling a robot and a massive issue I am having is the lack of functions. When I use Qt Designer, everything is imported afterwards, and I have imported sys, but I was looking to use what is called the close, show, or triggered methods. However, once I go to use the methods they are always whited out, and when I run the methods, Visual Studio indicates those methods don't exist. Is there something I am missing? I uninstalled PyQt5, reinstalled, and tried PyQt6 and 4 but none the less have the same issue.

Comment: Methods of what class/instance? You're not trying to modify a pyuic generated file, are you? Please try to add more details, as right now your question is unclear.

Comment: Hey. Put your code here so we can check it.  And include a screenshot whited-out methods in visual studio.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.